# Javascript variable scope in callbacks as closures

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, anonymous-function

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

pubnub.subscribe ({
    connect: function(m){

        var channelLatestMessages = [];

        pubnub.history({
          channel: broadcastChannel,
          count: 1,
          callback: function (m) {
            if(m[0].length > 0)
            {
                $.each(m[0], function(index, value){
                    channelLatestMessages.push(value);
                });
            }
            //THE NUMBER OF MESSAGE OBJECTS RETURNED IS 2
            //HERE THE OUTPUT IS 2
            console.info(channelLatestMessages.length);
          },
        }); 

        //THE NUMBER OF MESSAGE OBJECTS RETURNED IS 2
        //HERE THE OUTPUT IS 0          
        console.info(channelLatestMessages);
    }
});
```

});

If I declare:

```
channelLatestMessages = [];
```

without the `var` keyword and after page load issue I in Firebug console:

```
console.info(channelLatestMessages.length);
```

the number is `2`.

But I get `channelLatestMessages.length` value of `0` in the code again.

How is this possible???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Because in the one case you test the length *after* the event that causes the callback to run is fired and in the other you test it before then.